# Removal of :hover effect, after using toggleClass to scale object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I can't figure out what is the best way to do this, or just how to do this, so anything can help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $('.logo').toggleClass('logo-active');
        });
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $('.text').toggleClass('text-active');
        });});
```

I have this code and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xsx4pjk/) and i would like to remove the :hover effect, when the box is scaled to big and the text appears. So when .logo-active is activated, :hover should be disabled. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `transform: scale(1.0);` to `.logo-active`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $('.logo').toggleClass('logo-active');
  });
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $('.text').toggleClass('text-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.logo {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    
    transform: scale(0.8);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.logo:hover {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo-active {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
     transform: scale(1.0);
}

.text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.text-active {
    margin-top: -50px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button" class="logo">
        <p class="text">Hello / Hi</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just as simple as the other, but doesn't scale the text!

Comment: You can simply add `transform: scale(1.0);` to `.text` too.

Answer (score 0):

Your logo has an initial scale of 0.8 so adding this to the bottom of the css code will work (tested on your jsfiddle).

```
.logo-active:hover {
  transform: scale(.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra class and toggle it

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#button").click(function() {
            $('.logo').toggleClass('logo-active');
            $('.logo').toggleClass('logo_hover')

        });
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $('.text').toggleClass('text-active');
        });
});


.logo_hover:hover {
  transform: scale(1.0);
  cursor: pointer;
}


<div id="button" class="logo logo_hover">
    <p class="text">Hello / Hi</p>
</div>
```

See jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/1xsx4pjk/3/